# Sliding drop-down is not working perfectly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, fadeout

I am trying to add animation to my dropdown-menu ... It is working perfectly on large screens but on small phones and tablets (when toggle navigation appears) there is a problem: when it should slide up the drop-down list disappears without sliding up properly as you can see in my 
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/H_AL/u9pvtLpw/1/)  . Please try to open in it in small browser size and click on "services" to slide down and up .

I have tried another solution using jquery:

```
$(function () {
            $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
            });

            // ADD SLIDEUP ANIMATION TO DROPDOWN //
            $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(400, function () {
                    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
                    $('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                });

            });
        });
```

But as you can see in this [Bootply DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/render/ZFpB6GNtb6) (resize your browser to a phone screen size), when sliding down, at the end there is a gray space that appears then disappears directly.

What I really need is a normal working slide animation down and up. Any suggestions of how can I adjust at least one of both methods?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution , you should remove the scrollbar from the navbar.
**so add this simple code to your css file :**

```
.navbar-collapse {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

you can take a look at the Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/u9pvtLpw/2/

Comment: Still not working, try to see your demo when screen size is too small ... the same problem when hiding "services" drop down list. There is no problem when screen is big ...

Comment: @H.Al oh i didn't see that , if i find a solution for that one i will share